# Responsive website not working only in iPhone

Tags: iphone, responsive-design

[This website](http://thoughtbox.net.in/)

This above website works fine in every browser and mobile phone but not working only in iPhone.

Can anyone give me any hit so that I can investigate?

Comment: What issues you are facing?

Comment: You will only be able to see the issue in phone only. In all other phones there are 6 square boxes they perfectly okay in every phone, but when you open it in iphone those boxes are merged in one another.

Comment: Did you apply normalize.css or reset.css and auto-prefixer ?